# Error in booting ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a dual booted system with ubuntu and windows 10. On loading ubuntu, the following error is showing. How can i fix this? [error page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p10Jr.jpg)

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: I had an issue uploading the picture from phone. Will upload from pc in a few minutes

Comment: image added.So please help. If not fixable ill have to reinstall the entire ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried what is suggests already? `fsck /dev/sda4`

Comment: @CelticWarrior i tried it but it just does a few checks and creates a screen with endless 0's and 1's. I had to force shutdown the system with the off/on button.

Comment: Checking/correcting a file system takes a **long** time. You clearly haven't waited enough and by forcing the shutdown you just made the problem worse.